# Middy is not getting a secret from Secret Manager in a NodeJS AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am using [Middy](https://github.com/middyjs/middy) for getting secrets from Secret Manager in a NodeJS AWS Lambda. I did create a role for the Lambda to gain access to the parameter path, but some unknown reason the value is not setting either the context object or the environment variables.

The value of `process.env.SSM_PATH` is LAMBDA.

This is the code that I am using.

```
'use strict';

const middy = require('middy');
const { ssm } = require('middy/middlewares');


const handler = async (event, context) => {
    console.log(context);
    console.log(process.env)
    console.log(event);
};

exports.handler = middy(handler).use(ssm({
    setToContext: true,
    paths: {
        'PARAMETER': `/${process.env.SSM_PATH}/PARAMETER`
    }
}));
```

This is a portion of the policy in IAM for the Lambda.

```
{
    "permissionsBoundary": {},
    "roleName": "monitor_lambda_role",
    "policies": [
        {
            "document": {
                "Version": "2012-10-17",
                "Statement": [
                    {
                        "Sid": "",
                        "Effect": "Allow",
                        "Action": "sqs:sendMessage",
                        "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1::signed-resources-sqs"
                    },
                    {
                        "Sid": "",
                        "Effect": "Allow",
                        "Action": "ssm:GetParametersByPath",
                        "Resource": "arn:aws:ssm:us-east-1::parameter/LAMBDA/*"
                    },
                    {
                        "Sid": "",
                        "Effect": "Allow",
                        "Action": "kms:Decrypt",
                        "Resource": "arn:aws:ssm:us-east-1::alias/aws/ssm"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "name": "InlinePolicy",

            "arn": "arn:aws:iam:::policy/InlinePolicy"
        }
}
```

Could be due to the lambda run in an async way, it doesn't wait for the ssm middleware for getting the secrets?

Comment: Lol. I thought _Middy_ was the name of your colleague. Can you post the IAM Role Policy?

Comment: @Asdfg I updated the question. Thanks.

Comment: parameter path does not match. Try resource * and see if that works. If so, update the path in the policy.

Comment: You should consider updating the version of middy you're using. There have been quite a few improvements performance and security since 0.x. 2.x alpha is expected to drop in the coming weeks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem.

There is [two options for specifying](https://github.com/middyjs/middy/tree/master/packages/ssm) the secrets that you want to read:

> paths (object) (optional*): Map of SSM paths to fetch parameters from,
> where the key is the prefix for the destination name, and value is the
> SSM path. Example: {paths: {DB_: '/dev/service/db'}}

> names (object) (optional*): Map of parameters to fetch from SSM, where
> the key is the destination, and value is param name in SSM. Example:
> {names: {DB_URL: '/dev/service/db_url'}}

In my particular case, I should use the `names` option.